# How to place image and text next to each other on center of the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website using CSS and HTML as part of a school assignment and I cannot figure out how to get my text and image neatly aligned on the center of the page. Example of what I want: https://chagaimweiss.com/

I've been looking up solutions on line but nothing's worked and my code is just confusing me even more. (I've never done this before, I'm an absolute beginner.) I'm posting the entire code just because I'm afraid some element might be messing up others.

```css
html {
    font-size: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.6em
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 70%;

}

center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}


p {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
    clear: both;

}

.box {


    display : flex;
    justify-content : center;
    align-items : center;
    margin-left : 25px;
    margin-right : 25px;
}

.text {
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>TITLE</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.asp">Resume</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h1>Title</h1>

  <div class="box">
    <center>
      <img src="Profile_photo.jpg" alt="Profile Photo"/>

      <span style="p" class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
        <br>
        <br>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

      </span>
    </center>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is nowhere close to even being right. I'm not sure you've looked into this at all. Do a bit more research and tells us what you tried. look into HTML CSS positions

Comment: In order for us to answer the most specific way possible we need more details of what you've tried. Also a hint: a quick google search yields the first result about your use of the <center> tag being deprecated in HTML5. The <center> tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead. The <center> tag is used to center-align text.

Comment: Have a look here for some solutions for centering content: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to position two elements next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483417/how-to-position-two-elements-next-to-each-other)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You state "I've never done this before, I'm an absolute beginner." -- is building this site something you are attempting in the context of a larger plan to learn development?  Or just something you are trying to do for some unrelated school project?

Comment: @AlexanderNied Try reading the first line in the post, "I'm creating a website using CSS and HTML as part of a school assignment"

Comment: @GammaGames - I understand that-- what is not clear is if the school assignment is for _a class in web development_ or if this is just for a class unrelated to web dev where the OP has decided to make a website part of some project/deliverable.  Given the presence of a [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) element I actually believe it may be the latter.

Comment: @AlexanderNied I have a feeling you're right about it being the latter, I've seen classes required for business degrees that would have an assignment to make a portfolio page without any real guidance on how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what your are searching for

```css
.container {
  display: flex;    /* <--- This does the trick */
  max-width: 860px; /* Limit the width */
  margin: 0 auto;   /* Centering the container */
  
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 2;
}

.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.image-section {
  width: 50%;
  /* background: #3C86FF; */
}


.text-section {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 14px;
  /* background: #8D3CFF; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-section"><img class="responsive" src="https://i.imgur.com/GuAB8OE.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="text-section">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae adipisci ipsam eius sit nobis iure exercitationem officia quos earum eligendi?</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>index</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html {
      font-size: 100%;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 1.6em
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    li {
      display: inline;
    }
    
    li a {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #333;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    li a:hover {
      background-color: #f3f3f3;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 14px 16px;
    }
    
    h1 {
      font-family: Helvetica;
      font-size: 90px;
      font-weight: 400;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 30px;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    img {
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      border-radius: 100%;
    }
    
    p {
      overflow: hidden;
      float: right;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    .box {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .text {
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 17px;
      line-height: 26px;
      font-weight: 500;
      color: #333;
    }
    
    center {
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 300px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
    }
    
    center .text {
      padding: 0;
      -webkit-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
      flex: 1;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .text {
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 18px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #333;
      }
      img {
        width: 330px;
        height: 330px;
        border-radius: 100%;
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .text {
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 16px;
        font-weight: 500;
        color: #333;
      }
      img {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border-radius: 100%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="news.asp">Resume</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="box">
      <center>
        <span class="text">
                    <img src="https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/5bda793b0dbda3f980201462/1541898879554-U3DFRQS8QDCYCCHNICSG/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kE18-4zwLU-qbiNthgfATgZ7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QPOohDIaIeljMHgDF5CVlOqpeNLcJ80NK65_fV7S1Ue5QMtRsKNQ0Y8f36XeapJ7hOyTFdhnyFq38bJ63oibyFlq8oZZwhhoTbTOjCpwBwg/chagaiweiss.jpeg" alt="Profile Photo" />
                </span>
        <span class="text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
                <br>
                <br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
              </span>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```